# How to set images and textviews in ViewPager with serial per page from JSON in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am Design Layout using `ViewPager` in android. I am already get the data from json.. Iam set all images and related image names into ViewPager but it displays each image per page and when we scrolling back those images are gone.. but my agenda is 3images and image names set into each page(means each page having 3images and those names) in ViewPager in android.. any body knows solutions please reply me.

I upload and attach my Layout image for understanding purpose..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) in order to keep all your page "alive".

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.
>   (...)
>   If you have a small number of pages (3-4) that you can keep active
>   all at once, less time will be spent in layout for newly created view
>   subtrees as the user pages back and forth.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion